# Check if git tag is some parent or child

Tags: git, git-tag

Is there a way to find out if a tag is a child or parent (not the direct child or  parent)?

Imagine the following git history:

```
a467066 - (tag: child-2, master) feature 4
2028351 - (tag: child-1) feature 3
a7a6364 - (HEAD) feature 2
3772445 - (tag: parent-1) feature 1
5a01bfa - (tag: parent-2) initial commit
```

My `HEAD` is in the middle changeset ("feature 2") and I want to know if a tag is any child to the current changeset. So for `child-1` and `child-2` I want a `true`, checking the tags `parent-1`, `parent-2` or any `not-existing` would return `false`.

Comment: Try `git tag --contains HEAD`, this will list all tags that contains the HEAD commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `git tag --contains HEAD`

   It lists all the tags that are descendants of `HEAD`
2. `git merge-base <tag> <HEAD>`

   If it returns the commit of `HEAD`, then `tag` is a descendant of `HEAD`.
3. `git merge-base --is-ancestor <tag> <HEAD>`

   If `tag` is an ancestor of `HEAD`, the command's exit status is 0.